# auto-release pool dillema

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

So I have a question about auto-release pool. I created one use it as following:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
            NSMutableAttributedString * attributedString = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:object.text];
            [attributedString setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15]];
            [self.titleLabel_ setAttributedString:attributedString];
            [self.titleLabel_ setLinkColor:self.textColor_];
            [self parseTagsInComment];
            [pool release];
        });
```

Is this a wrong use of an auto-release pool because I already have an auto-released object?

Comment: This is probably overkill - when the runLoop finishes in the iteration that handles this block, the autorelease pool is flushed anyway. Autorelease pools are seldomly need particularly on iOS. On OSX if you are crunching some HUGE number of items they can be of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES this is right. All the `autoreleased` objects within the `pool` will get `release` message after `[pool release];` 
Thus flushed from the memory if their retain count becomes `0` as in your case `NSMutableAttributedString` and `UIFont` will be released.

Comment: but won't they be autoreleased even without the auto-release pool? what's the difference?